# Magento Varien_Form: addField() which fields are possible?

Tags: forms, magento

For Magento Backend I created a Varien_Form to display.

```
class MyNamespace_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_MyModule_Edit_Tabs_Form
        extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {    
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('my_form', array('legend'=>'ABC'));

        $fieldset->addField('data', 'text',
            array(
                'label' => 'My Textfield',
                'name' => 'myTextField'
            ));
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

My question is now, which form fields are possible at all? You see the function addField() where it says 'text'? I heard of 'checkbox' and 'hidden'. But is there a list of all possible fields? Like Label or a textbox for more lines etc. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The different form elements you can use are all found in lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element, you can find help using some of them at http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-admin-form-field

You can use textarea for a multiline textbox.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a list of possible field types:

```
text 
time 
textarea 
submit 
select 
radio 
password 
note 
multiselect
link
label
image
file
date 
checkbox
```